# using load function with variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, load

filterSize
sz = sprintf( '%dx%d', filterSize, filterSize );

I have some .mat files named

> results_3x3.mat

> results_5x5.mat

and so on..

I am importing that files with load function. But since that I have 20 files I need to do it in a for loop.  `filterSize=3:2:41`

I need to use the `load` function in MATLAB with variables.
I am now doing it manually as follows:

```
F1_score_3 = load('results_3x3.mat');
accuracy_3 = F1_score_3.accuracy;

F1_score_5 = load('results_5x5.mat');
accuracy_5 = F1_score_5.accuracy;

F1_score_7 = load('results_7x7.mat');
accuracy_7 = F1_score_7.accuracy;
```

`F1_score_3 = load('results_&s.mat',sz);` doesn't work.

Can you help me with this? Also, can I define variables with another variable in them? Such as

```
F1_score_%d, filterSize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create dynamic variable names that contain numbers like this. They will be hard to work with downstream in your code. It would be better to store the results in an array or cell or struct. E.g., you could do something like this using a cell array:

```
F1_score = cell(41,1);
for filterSize=3:2:41
    fname = sprintf( 'results_%dx%d.mat', filterSize, filterSize );
    F1_score{filterSize} = load(fname);
end
```

Then when you want to get at accuracy, you can use indexing as usual. E.g.,

```
F1_score{3}.accuracy
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an error saying that 

>Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Comment: I need to know how to reach the struct that I loaded as 'F1_score{filterSize} = load(fname);' and get the accuracy vector.

Comment: I don't have your mat files so I can't know what variables and types you are loading. Once you do the load, examine the F1_score{3} variable to see what was loaded etc.

Comment: So, the load function loads the .mat file as a struct to the cell. And I need to reach a vector from that .mat file.

Comment: Isn't F1_score{3} a struct? Doesn't it have a field named accuracy?

Comment: No, when I execute  F1_score{filterSize} = load(fname);

.mat file loads as struct to F1_score{filterSize} cell.

Comment: What is class(F1_score) and class(F1_score{3})?

Comment: So, at the end, F1_score is a 41x1 cell with 1x1 structs in it.

Comment: So doesn't that mean that class(F1_score{3}) is a struct? What does fieldnames(F1_score{3}) show?

Comment: class(F1_score) is cell and class(F1_score{3}) is struct.

Comment: fieldnames(F1_score{3}) is 43×1 cell array which have 43 different arrays, variables vectors etc. from my .mat file

Comment: Is one of those names 'accuracy'?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the curly braces { } and not parentheses ( )?

Comment: F1_score = cell(41,1);  makes a 41x1 cell. How can I reach the second row of this 41x1 cell?

I tried F1_score {i,:} but it didn't work

Comment: Both of the answers is yes. accuracy and {}

Comment: F1_score is a 41x1 cell array, and only some of these cells were assigned struct variables from the load process. F1_score{3} should contain the struct for the 3x3, F1_score{5} should contain the struct for the 5x5, etc. If these structs have a fieldname 'accuracy', then the syntax F1_score{3}.accuracy should work. You might try it in two steps. E.g., temp = F1_score{3} and then temp.accuracy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it. I solved my problem by using filterCount{i,:} in the for loop. Couldn't do it without your help.

Comment: OK. I don't know what filterCount is so can't comment on that. But as long as your problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry I mean F1_score